# Prototype of a class that inherits from a template class in virtual public mode

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, polymorphism, prototype

The prototype class of this:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass
{};
```

is simply:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass;
```

But what's the prototype of this class:

```
template <typename T>
class MyDerivedClass : public virtual MyBaseClass<T>
{};
```

If I just remove the `{}`, I get an error:

> expected '{' before ';' token

Is this even possible? I'm using gcc 6.2.1 on Debian Stretch.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Inheritance is part of the definition for a class, so you can't put it in a forward declaration.

Comment: @TartanLlama I want this class to be recognized to a class that is written before it, in addition to my personal curiosity.

Comment: This is not a "prototype". Use the term "declaration".

Comment: I've renamed your derived class for clarity and to make it easier to write an example in the answer.

Comment: _"It's very likely that this is a duplicate, but I gave up searching for it. 20 minutes on google and SO couldn't provide an answer."_ Next time please put more effort into your prior research. Twenty minutes is nothing. Read and study your C++ book, in order to learn the language.

Comment: There is no such thing as class prototype. Only functions have prototypes. A class only has a name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inheritance specifier is part of a class's definition, not its declaration.

You can of course still declare the class, just not its inheritance relationship:

```
template <typename T>
class MyDerivedClass;
```

Comment: How can I get a class that's written before this class to recognize it (both in 1 file)? That's not possible too?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist: What do you mean by "recognise it"? Recognise it how? Why do you need to know an inheritance relationship before you provided the class definitions? What are you trying to do?